# Rotate towards the mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I want to rotate a cube towards the mouse position (in 2d) in unity (c#). I have this code, but i doesn't work:

```
Vector3 a = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunTop").transform.position;
Vector3 b = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunBottom").transform.position;
Vector3 c = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.x);
float aTob = Vector3.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunTop").transform.position, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunBottom").transform.position);
float aToc = Vector3.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunTop").transform.position, new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.x));
float bToc = Vector3.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunBottom").transform.position, new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.x));

float winkel = Mathf.Acos(((Vector3.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunTop").transform.position, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunBottom").transform.position) * Vector3.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunTop").transform.position, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunBottom").transform.position)) + (Vector3.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunBottom").transform.position, new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.x)) * Vector3.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunBottom").transform.position, new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.x))) - (Vector3.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunTop").transform.position, new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.x)) * Vector3.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunTop").transform.position, new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.x)))) / (2 * Vector3.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunTop").transform.position, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunBottom").transform.position) * Vector3.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunBottom").transform.position, new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.x))));

private void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, winkel);
}
```

GunTop and GunBottom are the highest an lowest points in the middle of the cube, to create a triangle with the mouse.Does someone see the problem?

Edit1:
Okay, good news. Now I have to ways to solve the Problem. First one like memBrain sad(i changed it a bit):

```
`    private void Update()
{
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle - 90);
}`
```

I had to change it a bit in order to work with unity. The second solution, i could optimize my code, so it works now:

```
`   float winkel;
float echterWinkel;
float aTob;
float aToc;
float bToc;
private void Update()
{
    Vector3 a = 
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunTop").transform.position;
    Vector3 b = 
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunBottom").transform.position;
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    aTob = Vector3.Distance(a, b);
    aToc = Vector3.Distance(a, dir);
    bToc = Vector3.Distance(b, dir);
    winkel = Mathf.Acos(((aTob * aTob) + (bToc * bToc) - (aToc * aToc)) / (2 
  * aTob * bToc));
    echterWinkel = Mathf.Rad2Deg * winkel;
    if (dir.x < 0)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, echterWinkel);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -echterWinkel);
    }
   }
 }`
```

Okay, so far so good. But I have to questions now. Obviously the first solution is the better one, so I want to know how it works, what does "Mathf.Atan2()"?

And now the seconds question: Why do  I have to do this

```
   `Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;`
```

in order to get the real mouesposition?

Comment: Is Input.mousePosition in screen space?  If so, then that is at least one part of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, i thought this is a part, how can i get the mouseposition?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems needlessly complicated to me.  Is there a particular reason you need all those vectors?  Nevertheless, the following code is an example from the Unity forum (http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/731922/rotate-object-to-face-mouse-2d-rotate-on-z-axis.html) that you can use to rotate an object around the z-axis.

```
Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
```

It's really as simple as that.

Edit: Keep in mind that the transform will be the transform of your target GameObject.

On a side note, the non-functioning code in your example is rather inefficient.  You have declared vectors that you don't use, and floats you don't use.  So you can replace a lot of your code using these stored values instead.

```
Vector3 a = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunTop").transform.position;
Vector3 b = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GunBottom").transform.position;
Vector3 c = new Vector3 (
    Input.mousePosition.x, 
    Input.mousePosition.y, 
    Input.mousePosition.x
);
float aTob = Vector3.Distance(a, b);
float aToc = Vector3.Distance(a, c);
float bToc = Vector3.Distance(b, c);

float winkel = Mathf.Acos (
    (
        (
            aTob * aTob
        ) + 
        (
            bToc * bToc
        ) -
        (
            aToc * aToc
        )
    ) / 
    (
        2 * aTob * bToc
    )
);

private void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, winkel);
}
```

Note how much simpler the code now looks after properly using your stored values.  I also took the liberty of using the parenthesis like curly braces to make long lines of code more readable.  You need to keep one thing in mind.  Lookups are potentially expensive.  Never do a lookup more than once if you don't have to.

I haven't bothered checking to see if the code is correct.  I can't even verify that your lookups will return a value.  In fact, that is potentially going to be a problem for this code.  If either lookup fails, you will have null values stored in either a or b or both!  You need some kind of conditional check to verify that a and b had successful lookups, and what to do if they didn't.  As it now stands, you are going to have a failure the moment you try to perform an operation on either a or b the first time they are used.  The objective is to fail gracefully, not forcefully.

Edit 2: Looking over everything again, I noticed one other problem.  Your intention is to rotate around the z-axis, and you are setting the z-coordinate to Input.mousePosition.x.  This is wrong.  You should set it to a fixed value, like '0'.  You don't want z tied to x.

Edit 3: [Here is the information provided by the Unity Scripting API for Mathf.Atan2(...)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Atan2.html).

Yes. those two lines are related to obtaining the mouse position.  Let me explain what is happening here.

```
Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
```

This line converts the world coordinate (transform.position) of your "gun" object to a screen point coordinate and stores it in pos.

```
Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
```

This line takes the mousePosition vector and subtracts from it the position vector (pos) from before, and stores it in dir (presumably for "direction").  You could just as easily change your Vector3 c as follows:

```
Vector3 c = Input.mousePosition;
```

This is equivalent to what you did without needing to create the new Vector3 and assigning it the vector coordinates explicitly as you did.

```
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
```

This line replaces winkel.  Consequently, your entire code can be condensed as follows:

```
GameObject gun;

void Start()
{
    /*
        initialization code for gun GameObject
    */
}

void Update()
{
    Vector3 gunScreenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gun.transform.position);
    Vector3 mouseDirection = Input.mousePosition - gunScreenPosition;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(mouseDirection.y, mouseDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    gun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
}
```

You really don't need all the extra code you were using.  Is there a particular reason you needed GunTop and GunBottom?  If it's just to calculate the position for the gun, my example is all that you need.

I'd be remiss if I didn't share one more thing.  Be careful when using Quaternion.Euler(...).  It can suffer from a condition known as "[gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)"

Comment: Wow, thank you, this was very helpfully. I wanted to used the stored values, but unity didn't allow it, so i took the not stored values. And i needed the vectors to create a triangle and use arcos to get the angle.I will try your code and I will try to do my code right. A big thank you to you:)

Comment: You're welcome.  Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: @Gmunderos7, I have provided a link to the documentation on MathF.Atan2 from Unity's web site.  I also copied over your "answer" as an edit to your original post (pending moderation).  It is my understanding that it is better for you to extend your original post rather than adding new answers.  As such, I'd recommend deleting your post once my edit has been moderated.

Comment: Okey, thank you. So the first line i need to convert the gun.Position from world space to screen space, than i can subtract the gun position in order to get the mouse Position relative to the gun position, is this correct? And i need to convert the gun position in order to subtract it, is this right? Would it also be possible to convert the mouse position to world space in order to subtract?